# ¿Como limitar para mostrar un texto en JS y mostrar la fecha correctamente con JS?

Tags: javascript, html, json

ojala me puedan ayudar a resolver este inconveniente que tengo, ya que se me dificulta trabajar con JS.

Tengo el siguiente código el cual es una (API) que me muestra varia información:

```
 $(function (){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "(url-de-la.api)",
            dataType: "html",
            // async: "false",
            data: {
                autor: 32,
                metodo: "lista",
                limite: 3
                }
        }).done(function (msg) {
            let result = JSON.parse(msg);
            // console.log(result)
            let html = '';

            $(result).each(function(index,item){

                html += '<div class="col-md-4">'+
                        '<img src="'+item.imagen+'" width="100%" height="200px"><br>'+
                        '<p>'+item.fecha+'<br>'+item.contenido+'</p>'+
                        '<div id="nota-completa">'+
                            '<a title="'+item.titulo+'" href="'+item.url+'" target="_blank">'+
                                '<img id="img-nota-completa" src="completa.png">'+
                            '</a>'+
                        '</div>'+
                        '</div>';

            });

            $('#noticia').append(html);

        });

    });
</script>
```

y luego la muestro así en mi html:

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="noticia" class="row"  style="height: 20px;">

    </div>
</div>
```

La fecha me la muestra de esta forma:

**`2019-07-08`**

¿cómo puedo hacer que me aparezca 08 de Julio del 2019?

La parte de contenido me muestra mucha informacion, como puedo limitar a que solo me muestre 100 caracteres de ese texto?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Te propongo que uses el método `toLocaleString()` que retornará un valor en un idioma específico:

```js
    
    let fecha = new Date();
    
    let mes = fecha.toLocaleString('es-419', { month: 'long' });
    let dia = fecha.getDate()
    let anio = fecha.getFullYear()
    
    console.log(`${dia} de ${mes} del ${anio}`)
```

**Explicación**

- Obtenemos con `fecha` la fecha actual para transformarla al formato solicitado

  - Como primer parámetro indicamos la referencia de `locale` en este caso la codificación será `es-419` para obtener el nombre del mes en español
  - Para obtener el nombre del mes completo, pasamos como segundo argumento un objeto con el valor `long` lo cual debe retornar `Julio`
- Obtenemos el día y el año con `getDate()` y `getFullYear()`
- Finalmente concatenamos con ayuda de la sintaxis de template strings el valor en formato mas legible y obtendremos en pantalla algo como:

> "10 de julio del 2019"

**Referencias**

- [`toLocaleString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString)

Comment: Oye @Rubén gracias por la edición, totalmente pasé por alto dichos errores de redacción.

Answer (score 2):

Para la manipulación de fechas te recomiendo utilizar [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/). Con [`format()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) definís como querés mostrar la fecha y le cargás el idioma que quieras con [`locale()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/).

```js
moment.locale('es');

var fecha = moment('2019-07-08').format('DD [de] MMMM [del] YYYY');
$('#fecha').text(fecha);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/locale/es.js"></script>

<time id="fecha"></time>
```

No se necesita jQuery, solo lo usé a modo de ejemplo porque vi que lo estás usando.

En cuanto a cortar una cadena, podes utilizar [`substring()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/substring).

```js
var texto = 'Texto largo que se quiere acortar a 10 caracteres';
var largo = 10;

$('#texto').text(texto.substring(0, largo));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span id="texto"></span>
```